# Inserting information into a table on SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to insert new information into an already existing table. This is my code which is not working:

```
INSERT INTO customer (cNo, cName, street, city, county, discount)
VALUES (10, Tom, Long Street, Short city, Wide County, 2);
```

Where am I going wwrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not specifying your strings properly it should be:

```
INSERT INTO customer (cNo, cName, street, city, county, discount) 
VALUES (10, 'Tom', 'Long Street', 'Short city', 'Wide County', 2);
```

Answer (score 4):

You must use quotes for string values:

```
INSERT INTO customer (cNo, cName, street, city, county, discount)
VALUES (10, 'Tom', 'Long Street', 'Short city', 'Wide County', 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You must separate values with a comma, and enclose text fields in quotation marks (' ').
 check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Try this code:

```
INSERT INTO customer (cNo, cName, street, city, county, discount) 
VALUES (10, 'Tom', 'Long Street', 'Short city', 'Wide County', 2);
```